# Clicking buttons inside Angular Material's Card triggers the click event of the card itself

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a `mat-card` inside a component template:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let p of products" (click)="viewProduct(p)">
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addProductToCart(p)">Add to cart</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

The issue is that when clicking on the button angular invokes both `addProductToCart` and `viewProduct`.

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just stop bubbling click event by using [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method:

Here's how it looks in Angular:

```
<button ... (click)="addProductToCart(p); $event.stopPropagation()">Add to cart</button>
```